# code-first models mapped incorrectly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to SQL and I'm having some trouble mapping some objects together. I have an Account object and a User object.

The account object uses `Email` for it's primary key. The user object uses `Username` as it's primary key.

I want the `Username` field in AccountModel to act as a foreign key to the user model but it doesn't seem to work. The User object `Username` is being set to the `Email` field

```
public class AccountModel : IAccountModel
{
    public AccountModel() { }

    [Key]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string VerifyURL { get; set; }
    public bool Verified { get; set; }
    public DateTime URLValidSince { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual UserModel User { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel : IUserModel
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Account")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual AccountModel Account { get; set; }
}

public static void main() {
        AccountModel acc = new AccountModel(email, password, username);
        UserModel user = new UserModel(username);

        acc.User = user;
        user.Account = acc;

        this.DBUtilites.Insert(acc);
}

public T Insert<T>(T t) where T : class {
    try
    {
        using (DBUtilities ctx = new DBUtilities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionStr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            DbSet<T> dbSet = ctx.Set<T>();

            dbSet.Add(t);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Inserting Entity: " + ex);
        int exceptionNo = HandleException(ex);
    }
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Addition after comment at the end**

It seems to me you want to configure a one-to-one relation between User and Account: every User has exactly one Account, and every Account is owned by exactly one User. There are no Users without Account, and no Accounts without Users.

Normally a one-to-one is best configured using Composition: Every User has exactly one Account. The result will be that a User and his Account are in one table, thus speeding up queries. Besides it is easier to ensure that there are no Users without Accounts, or Accounts without users. It will also be easier to change the Account data of a given User.

In entity framework you would do this like:

```
class Account
{
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;} // by the way: very unsave, prone to be hacked
    ...
}

class User
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public Account Account {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

The effect will be that Account and User will be in one table.

To get some User properties with some Account properties of a user with a given name would be like:

```
var result = myDbContext.Users
    .Where(user => user.Name = ...)
    .Select(user => new
    {   // get only the properties you plan to use:
        Name = user.Name,
        ...

        // only if you also need some account properties:
        Account = new
        {
            Email = user.Account.Email,
            Password = user.Account.Password,
            ...
        },
     });
```

It might be that you didn't plan a real one-to-one, but a 
[one-to-zero-or-one relation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), allowing that some Users have no Account yet, or maybe some Accounts have no Users. This needs two tables:

```
class User
{
    ...

    // every user has zero or one Account:
    public virtual Account Account {get; set;}
}

class Account
{
    ...

    // every Account belongs to zero or one User
    public virtual User User  {get; set;}
}
```

Queries will be similar to the one I described above, except that you need to check if User.Account is null

**Finally: it is very unwise to use emails and names as primary keys**

Are you sure every User has a unique Name? If a User changes his Name (for instance because there is a typing error in it) will it be a different User?

Never, ever, use items that might change as a primary key. It is most efficient if you let the database decide about the value of the primary key:

```
class User
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     ...
}
class Account
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

Because I followed [the Entity Framework conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), this is enough for entity framework to understand that Id is the primary key, to be filled by the database. No need for attributes, nor fluent API. Entity Framework is also smart enough to detect the foreign keys if you follow the naming conventions:

one-to-many: suppose a User has zero or more Accounts, every Account is owned by exactly one User:

```
class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every user has zero or more Accounts:
    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts {get; set;}

    ...
}

class Account
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    // every Account belongs to exactly one User, using foreign key:
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Because of the followed conventions, entity framework detects your relation. It automatically knows the foreign key. It will make sure that you can't create an Account without its User.

**Addition: make sure that some values are unique**

Primary keys are always unique. You don't have to worry about that.

If you want other items to be unique, meaning that these value are still changeable, but the database won't accept it if you change them to a value that is already used, you should give it a unique index annotation. This is done in your DbContext.OnModelCreating.

Suppose every `Email` must be unique within the collection of 'Accounts'. You want to be able to give it a different value, but it is not allowed to give it a value that is already used by a different `Account`.

In your DbContext:

```
protected virtual OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // From table Accounts, give property Email a unique index annotation:
    const string indexName = "indexEmails"
    var indexAttribute  = new IndexAttribute(indexName, 0) {IsUnique = true};
    var indexAnnotation = new IndexAnnotation(indexAttribute);
    propertyEmail = modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
       .Property(account => account.Email)
       .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, indexAnnotation);
     ...
}
```

What you do is that you say that the email properties of Account should be put in an index. The name of the index is "indexEmails". All values in the index should be unique.

Now whenever you want to add or update an Account, the database wants to add the email to the index and asserts that this email value is not used yet.

You get the exception during your SaveChanges().

If you want a combination of two values to be unique, fr instance the combination (Email, Password) you'll have to give both properties an index annotation with the same name.

```
var entityAccount = modelBuilder.Entity<Account>();
var propertyEmail = entityAccount.Property(account => account.Email);
var propertyPassword = entityAccount.Property(account => account.Password);

// indes: first order by (0) email, then by (1) password
const string indexName = "IX_MyIndex");
var indexAttribute0  = new IndexAttribute(indexName, 0) {IsUnique = true};
var indexAnnotation0 = new IndexAnnotation(indexAttribute);
propertyEmail.HasUniqueIndexAcnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, indexAnnotation);

var indexAttribute1  = new IndexAttribute(indexName, 1) {IsUnique = true};
var indexAnnotation1 = new IndexAnnotation(indexAttribute);
propertyPassword.HasUniqueIndexAcnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, indexAnnotation);
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer! Also I'm hashes of the salted / peppered password but cheers for looking out for me.

Comment: "I'm hashes of the salted / peppered password" No idea what that means

Comment: Whoops - I'm still asleep. I'm only storing salted hashes of the passwords.

Comment: I just got it working like you suggested - merging them into a single table. One quick question - if I index on Id - how can I prevent a scenario where two requests come in with the same "email" at the same time? They would both be added with unique indexes but I would expect / want one to fail.

Comment: Thanks for your time - this answer is great.